# Remover atributos de una clase

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente codigo con la propiedad [Export()]

```
public class DiasGridViewModel
    {
       [Display(Name = "Fecha"]
       [Export()]
       public double Fecha { get; set; }
    }
```

Como puedo remover el atributo Export() desde un controlador?

Comment: eso es un meta tag.. una vez compilado, no se puede remover.. que queres hacer?

Comment: Borras la línea y listo. Probablemente no sea lo que esperas. Por cierto los paréntesis en los atributos no son necesarios a menos que indiques parámetros.

Comment: Dependiendo de la configuración que haya elegido el usuario, deberá respetar o no el Export()

Comment: creo que exportAttribute tiene configuraciones para que sea exportado según el caso, pero no recuerdo como van, revisa la documentación, seguro está ahí

Answer (score 0):

Una vez ejecutado el proyecto no hay como cambiar la característica del atributo.

Una opción que puedes implementar, seria lo siguiente:

```
namespace Dias
{
    public class DiasGridViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Fecha")]
        public double Fecha { get; set; }
    }

    public class DiasGridViewModelExport
    {
        [Display(Name = "Fecha")]
        [Export()]
        public double Fecha { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

1. Crear una clase igual dentro del mismo namespace sin la característica del Export()
2. También asegúrate de poner el paréntesis final a la característica del [Display()]